`xarray`: setting `drop=True` when filtering a `Dataset` causes `IndexError: dimension coordinate conflicts between indexed and indexing objects`
Some preliminary setup:
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

xr.set_options(display_style="text")

<xarray.core.options.set_options at 0x7f3777111e50>

Suppose that I have labels which are composed of two parts: first and second:
raw_labels = np.array(
    [["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["c", "a"]],
    dtype="<U1",
)
raw_labels

array([['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'a']], dtype='<U1')

I can make an xarray.DataArray easily enough to represent this raw information with informative tags:
label_metas = xr.DataArray(
    raw_labels,
    dims=("label", "parts"),
    coords={
        "label": ["-".join(x) for x in raw_labels],
        "parts": ["first", "second"],
    },
    name="meta",
)
label_metas

<xarray.DataArray 'meta' (label: 4, parts: 2)> Size: 32B
array([['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
Now suppose that I have additional information for a label: let's say it is some count information for simplicity.
raw_counts = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(label_metas))
raw_counts

array([95, 23,  6, 77])

label_counts = xr.DataArray(
    raw_counts,
    dims="label",
    coords={"label": label_metas.coords["label"]},
    name="count",
)
label_counts

<xarray.DataArray 'count' (label: 4)> Size: 32B
array([95, 23,  6, 77])
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
How do I combine these clearly related xr.DataArrays? From what I understand: by using xr.Datasets.
label_info = xr.merge([label_metas, label_counts])
label_info

<xarray.Dataset> Size: 160B
Dimensions:  (label: 4, parts: 2)
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
Data variables:
    meta     (label, parts) <U1 32B 'a' 'c' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'a'
    count    (label) int64 32B 95 23 6 77
Now suppose I want to filter this dataset, so that I only have left those labels with first part 'a'. How would I go about it? According to the docs, where can apply to xr.Dataset too, but no examples are given showing this in action. Here are the results of my experiments:
label_info["meta"].sel(parts="first")

<xarray.DataArray 'meta' (label: 4)> Size: 16B
array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
    parts    <U6 24B 'first'
label_info.where(label_info["meta"].sel(parts="first") == "a")

<xarray.Dataset> Size: 192B
Dimensions:  (label: 4, parts: 2)
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
Data variables:
    meta     (label, parts) object 64B 'a' 'c' nan nan 'a' 'b' nan nan
    count    (label) float64 32B 95.0 nan 6.0 nan
We see that those points that do not match the where are replaced with a np.nan, as expected from the docs. Does that mean there is some re-allocation of backing arrays involved? Suppose then that we just asked for those regions that do not match to be dropped, does that also cause a re-allocation? I am not sure, because I am unable to drop those values due to IndexError: dimension coordinate 'parts' conflicts between indexed and indexing objects:
label_info.where(label_info["meta"].sel(parts="first") == "a", drop=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 label_info.where(label_info["meta"].sel(parts="first") == "a", drop=True)


File ~/miniforge3/envs/xarray-tutorial/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py:1225, in DataWithCoords.where(self, cond, other, drop)
   1222     for dim in cond.sizes.keys():
   1223         indexers[dim] = _get_indexer(dim)
-> 1225     self = self.isel(**indexers)
   1226     cond = cond.isel(**indexers)
   1228 return ops.where_method(self, cond, other)


File ~/miniforge3/envs/xarray-tutorial/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:2972, in Dataset.isel(self, indexers, drop, missing_dims, **indexers_kwargs)
   2970 indexers = either_dict_or_kwargs(indexers, indexers_kwargs, "isel")
   2971 if any(is_fancy_indexer(idx) for idx in indexers.values()):
-> 2972     return self._isel_fancy(indexers, drop=drop, missing_dims=missing_dims)
   2974 # Much faster algorithm for when all indexers are ints, slices, one-dimensional
   2975 # lists, or zero or one-dimensional np.ndarray's
   2976 indexers = drop_dims_from_indexers(indexers, self.dims, missing_dims)


File ~/miniforge3/envs/xarray-tutorial/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:3043, in Dataset._isel_fancy(self, indexers, drop, missing_dims)
   3040 selected = self._replace_with_new_dims(variables, coord_names, indexes)
   3042 # Extract coordinates from indexers
-> 3043 coord_vars, new_indexes = selected._get_indexers_coords_and_indexes(indexers)
   3044 variables.update(coord_vars)
   3045 indexes.update(new_indexes)


File ~/miniforge3/envs/xarray-tutorial/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:2844, in Dataset._get_indexers_coords_and_indexes(self, indexers)
   2840 # we don't need to call align() explicitly or check indexes for
   2841 # alignment, because merge_variables already checks for exact alignment
   2842 # between dimension coordinates
   2843 coords, indexes = merge_coordinates_without_align(coords_list)
-> 2844 assert_coordinate_consistent(self, coords)
   2846 # silently drop the conflicted variables.
   2847 attached_coords = {k: v for k, v in coords.items() if k not in self._variables}


File ~/miniforge3/envs/xarray-tutorial/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/coordinates.py:941, in assert_coordinate_consistent(obj, coords)
    938 for k in obj.dims:
    939     # make sure there are no conflict in dimension coordinates
    940     if k in coords and k in obj.coords and not coords[k].equals(obj[k].variable):
--> 941         raise IndexError(
    942             f"dimension coordinate {k!r} conflicts between "
    943             f"indexed and indexing objects:\n{obj[k]}\nvs.\n{coords[k]}"
    944         )


IndexError: dimension coordinate 'parts' conflicts between indexed and indexing objects:
<xarray.DataArray 'parts' (parts: 2)> Size: 48B
array(['first', 'second'], dtype='<U6')
Coordinates:
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
vs.
<xarray.Variable ()> Size: 24B
array('first', dtype='<U6')


xarray was the wrong choice for my task, and probably every other task imaginable. polars turned out to be much better.
I think the reason why is:

an n-dimensional array is the same as an n-argument function
an n-argument function is the same as a "table" with n + 1 "columns", where the first n columns correspond to the function's input, and the last column corresponds to the function's output.

Therefore, everything that one might want to try and do with a multi-dimensional array can be done with a "flat" table (a DataFrame in polars speak), and the quality of polars is such that:

its documentation is much, much better than that of xarray;
its performance is much, much better than that of xarray.

When it comes to this question in particular, what I was trying to do is joining two n-dimensional maps, and then filter for particular rows. That's a kind of join operation in SQL/polars/etc. speak, followed by a filter.
It's an utter pain to do this in xarray. See this question, and related: `xarray`: merging two `DataArray`s which have only one shared dimension results in a `Dataset` that lists other dimensions?
It is easy to do in polars:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

raw_labels = np.array(
    [["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["c", "a"]],
    dtype="<U1",
)

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [pl.Series(col, dtype=pl.String()) for col in raw_labels.transpose()]
).rename({"column_0": "first", "column_1": "second"})
print(df)

# attach new data to the table
raw_counts = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=raw_labels.shape[0])
df.insert_column(len(df.columns), pl.Series("counts", raw_counts))
print(df)

# filter the dataframe for those rows where column `first` == "a"
df.filter(pl.col("first") == "a")
print(df)

shape: (4, 2) # create a table with first, second as columns
┌───────┬────────┐
│ first ┆ second │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ a     ┆ c      │
│ b     ┆ a      │
│ a     ┆ b      │
│ c     ┆ a      │
└───────┴────────┘
shape: (4, 3) # attach extra count information
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ first ┆ second ┆ counts │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ a     ┆ c      ┆ 71     │
│ b     ┆ a      ┆ 19     │
│ a     ┆ b      ┆ 46     │
│ c     ┆ a      ┆ 73     │
└───────┴────────┴────────┘
shape: (2, 3) # filter for those rows where column `first` == "a"
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ first ┆ second ┆ counts │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ a     ┆ c      ┆ 71     │
│ a     ┆ b      ┆ 46     │
└───────┴────────┴────────┘

